# OnComplete firing before certain function is completed ( Javascript / IndexedDB )

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm using IndexedDB to store data offline on an app I'm developing. My problem is that the transaction's OnComplete is being fired before the function responsible for storing the data is finished. I need to know how to to make the OnComplete wait this function do it's job before being fired.

This is what i have so a far... Function populateDatabase is used to store data. For that to happen, there are other two inside it.

```js
function populateDatabase() {
  var i = 0;
  requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, obtainDataFile, onError);
  try {
    if (localDatabase != null && localDatabase.db != null) {
      console.log('Started adding records');

      var transaction = localDatabase.db.transaction(osTableName, "readwrite");
      if (transaction) {
        transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
          console.log("transaction completed.");
          localDatabase.db.close();
        }
        transaction.onabort = function(event) {
          console.log("transaction aborted.");
          localDatabase.db.close();
        }
        transaction.ontimeout = function(event) {
          console.log("transaction timeout.");
          localDatabase.db.close();
        }

        var store = transaction.objectStore(osTableName);
        if (data.length > 0)
        {
          if (store)
            addData(transaction, store, data, 0, true);
        }

      }
      console.log('Finished adding records');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

obtainDataFile, that basically read data from a txt file and store in Data variable

```js
function obtainDataFile(fileSystem) {
  var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
  directoryEntry.getFile("EstoqueCSV.txt", {
    create: true,
    exclusive: false
  }, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend =
        function(evt) {
          var csv = evt.target.result;
          data = $.csv.toObjects(csv);
        };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }, onError)
  }, onError);
}
```

And this recursive function used to loop through the Data array in order to store the registers one by one.

```js
function addData(txn, store, records, i, commitT) {
  try {
    if (i < records.length) {
      var rec = records[i];
      var req = store.add(rec);
      req.onsuccess = function(ev) {
        i++;
        console.log("Adding record " + i);
        addData(txn, store, records, i, commitT);
      }
      req.onerror = function(ev) {
        console.log("Failed to add record." + "  Error: " + ev.message);
      }
    } else if (i == records.length) {
      console.log('Finished adding ' + records.length + " records");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

The problem is that my code reaches the transaction.oncomplete before addData function is finished. I'm not sure about what I should do in this case. I was looking for topics related to asynchronous calls, callback functions and things like that, but still not able to solve it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: So I know nothing about indexeddb but I took a quicklook at it for the fun of it. Shouldn't you use a transaction instead of that recursive function you are using now? This is based on the following example: Section "Adding data to the database" from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load all data before you start transaction. From your code I don't see `data` is loaded. Otherwise, your code looks correct.

Comment: Kyaw Tun, the data variable is loaded at the beggning of the populateDatabase method, on this line of code: `requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, obtainDataFile, onError);` which calls the obtainDataFile method. When I call the addData method, the data variable is allready fully loaded with the data from the txt file.

Comment: @Kaius it is clear from your code that `data` is not loaded when transaction starts.

Comment: You're right, I'm just not sure why. I did some test and when the code reaches the 'if (data.length > 0)' line, 'data' variable has no data, so the 'addData' function is not being called. The strange happens when I debug the code. If I set a break point on the conditional line, I can see the data "being loaded" into the 'data' variable a few seconds after the breakpoint is reached. It's like the 'obtainDataFile' is taking too much to execute, so the code continues and reaches the conditional before the data from the text file is fully loaded. Do you know how to deal with this behavior ? Thanks

Comment: If I load the data outside of the populateDatabase method, it works properly.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem... `requestFileSystem` is asynchronous, so whatever I need to do with the result of this call should be done on the `onloadend` callback. I just changed my `populateDatabase` method's place. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I have scaled down your problem in a much simpler way, as per your approach, and as expected it is working like a charm.

So, your approach and code looks clean, but since you are facing problem, now exact root cause can only be identified by looking into all your code.

One second thought is that `transaction.oncomplete` can be called before your data adding into database is done if there is some error while adding data. So, watch the console for any error, also add one more error handler - `transaction.onerror`

Also, give a try to using FOR loop instead of recursive function.

Please note that IndexedDB support in iOS is very buggy, if that is your case then unexpected should be expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Stackoverflow</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var dbDeleteRequest = window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase("toDoList");
            dbDeleteRequest.onerror = function(event) {
                console.log("Error while deleting database.", true);
            };

            dbDeleteRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
                // Let us open our database
                var DBOpenRequest = window.indexedDB.open("toDoList", 5);

                DBOpenRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
                  console.log('<li>Database initialised.</li>');

                  // store the result of opening the database in the db variable. This is used a lot below
                  db = DBOpenRequest.result;

                  // Run the addData() function to add the data to the database
                  addData();
                };

                DBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
                  console.log('<li>DBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded</li>');
                  var db = event.target.result;

                  db.onerror = function(event) {
                    console.log('<li>Error loading database.</li>');
                  };

                  // Create an objectStore for this database   //, { keyPath: "taskTitle" });  { autoIncrement : true }
                  var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("toDoList", { autoIncrement : true });

                  // define what data items the objectStore will contain

                  objectStore.createIndex("hours", "hours", { unique: false });
                  objectStore.createIndex("minutes", "minutes", { unique: false });
                  objectStore.createIndex("day", "day", { unique: false });
                  objectStore.createIndex("month", "month", { unique: false });
                  objectStore.createIndex("year", "year", { unique: false });
                  objectStore.createIndex("notified", "notified", { unique: false });
                };
            };

            function addData() {
              // Create a new object ready to insert into the IDB
              var newItem = [];
              newItem.push({ taskTitle: "Walk dog1", hours: 19, minutes: 30, day: 24, month: "December", year: 2013, notified: "no" });
              newItem.push({ taskTitle: "Walk dog2", hours: 19, minutes: 30, day: 24, month: "December", year: 2013, notified: "no" });
              newItem.push({ taskTitle: "Walk dog3", hours: 19, minutes: 30, day: 24, month: "December", year: 2013, notified: "no" });

              console.log(newItem);

              // open a read/write db transaction, ready for adding the data
              var transaction = db.transaction(["toDoList"], "readwrite");

              // report on the success of opening the transaction
              transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
                console.log('<li>Transaction completed: database modification finished.</li>' + new Date());
              };


              transaction.onerror = function(event) {
                console.log('<li>Transaction not opened due to error. Duplicate items not allowed.</li>');
              };

              // create an object store on the transaction
              var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("toDoList");

              addData2(transaction, objectStore, newItem, 0, true);

            };

            function addData2(txn, store, records, i, commitT) {
              try {
                if (i < 10000) {
                  var rec = records[i];
                  var req = store.add(rec);
                  req.onsuccess = function(ev) {
                    i++;
                    console.log("Adding record " + i + " " + new Date());
                    addData2(txn, store, records, i, commitT);
                  }
                  req.onerror = function(ev) {
                    console.log("Failed to add record." + "  Error: " + ev.message);
                  }
                } else if (i == records.length) {
                  console.log('Finished adding ' + records.length + " records");
                }
              } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
              }
            };
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

For loop approach:

```
              for(var i =0; i < 1000; i++){
                    // add our newItem object to the object store
                  var objectStoreRequest = objectStore.add(newItem[0]);

                  objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
                    // report the success of our new item going into the database
                    console.log('<li>New item added to database.</li>' + new Date());
                  };
              }
```

**EDIT: As per discussion in comments**

Update your `populateDatabase` to add a callback method while calling `requestFileSystem`. Also, update your `requestFileSystem` to accept one more parameter which will be callback, and call it in the end. I think your `requestFileSystem` has some asynchronous calls because of which that method is returning even before it is fully completed.

```
function populateDatabase() {
  var i = 0;
  requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, obtainDataFile, onError, function(){
      try {
        if (localDatabase != null && localDatabase.db != null) {
          console.log('Started adding records');

          var transaction = localDatabase.db.transaction(osTableName, "readwrite");
          if (transaction) {
            transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
              console.log("transaction completed.");
              localDatabase.db.close();
            }
            transaction.onabort = function(event) {
              console.log("transaction aborted.");
              localDatabase.db.close();
            }
            transaction.ontimeout = function(event) {
              console.log("transaction timeout.");
              localDatabase.db.close();
            }

            var store = transaction.objectStore(osTableName);
            if (data.length > 0)
            {
              if (store)
                addData(transaction, store, data, 0, true);
            }

          }
          console.log('Finished adding records');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
      }
  });
}
```

Accept callback for `requestFileSystem`

```
requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, obtainDataFile, onError, callback){
    //After your asynchronous processing (I am assuming based on your description of problem) is done... Probably you will have some event handler or something, so in the end of that use below call...
    if (callback && typeof(callback) == 'function') {
        callback(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but as soon as I add my function to load data from a text file the problem appears again. One detail I noted is that when I debug the code, it takes a few seconds for the `data` variable to be loaded, so the `requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, obtainDataFile, onError);` line is executed and the code continues, but is takes a while before the result appears inside `data`. If I wait the load, the code runs properly, but during a normal execution, the code reaches the conditional before this delayed load is complete. Do you have any thoughts about it ? Thanks

Comment: I think you have some asynchronous processing code, could be in your `requestFileSystem` because of which your IndexedDB code is getting executed at unexpected time. I have provided you code snippet (edit in my original answer) assuming asynchronous processing code is in `requestFileSystem`. If you have it at some other place then use similar approach. Let me know if the approach I am trying to highlight is not clear to you.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem... `requestFileSystem` is asynchronous, so whatever I need to do with the result of this call should be done on the `onloadend` callback. I just changed my `populateDatabase` method's place. Thanks for the help.